# Error when deleting rows in chunks from mysql table with 1M rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've two tables , person and person_history to keep versioned records of a person entity.

person table will always have the latest version of the person entity, while person_history table keeps all the versions of the person.

The table person_history is growing exponentially in size as with every update of person, a new record is added to the history table.

The primary key of person table is referenced as `person_id` from the person_history table. Column `version_num` keeps track of versioning in the history table. With each update, version_num is bumped up by 1.

I wish to keep only 5 records per person_id, and purge the older ones.

For this I've prepared the below statement

```
DELETE
        FROM person_history
        WHERE id in (SELECT p0.id
        FROM person_history p0
        WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM person_history pi
        WHERE  p0.person_id = p1.person_id AND p0.version_num < p1.version_num
        ) >= 5);
```

This statement works, but is very slow and write operations are impacted at that time.

I tried adding order and limit to above condition to delete it in chunks and formed below query

```
DELETE
        FROM person_history
        WHERE id in (SELECT p0.id
        FROM person_history p0
        WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM person_history pi
        WHERE  p0.person_id = p1.person_id AND p0.version_num < p1.version_num
        ) >= 5)
        ORDER BY p0.id 
        LIMIT 1000);
```

This query fails with error **This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'**

I've also tried creating a procedure and but that threw error too

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS purge_history;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE purge_history()

BEGIN   
    REPEAT
        DO SLEEP(1);
        SET @z:= (SELECT p0.id
            FROM person_history p0
            WHERE (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM person_history p1
            WHERE  p0.person_id = p1.person_id AND p0.version_num < p1.version_num
            ) >= 5 ORDER BY p0.id LIMIT 1000);
        DELETE
        FROM person_history
        WHERE id in z;
    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This failed with **ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'z;
UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;**

I've tried it on MySQL 8 and Mariadb 10.9

Please suggest any alternative to above chunk delete query so that the writes are not impacted while delete is in progress.

Comment: I'm surprised either of them works, you should be getting the "Can't specify target table for UPDATE" error.

Comment: The first one is working but took over 2 minutes to delete around 200K records. There are over 1M rows in the table out of which 200K records were to be purged.

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE id IN (...)`

Comment: Short answer:  Don't try to do it in a single `DELETE`.  Deletes are slow and block other things.

Comment: Is it 5 or is it 3?  Are the version numbers consecutive?  Or might there be gaps?

Comment: My bad, 3 was a typo. corrected it. was trying the query in local in 3 and pasted the same in stack. version numbers will be consecutive.

Comment: @RickJames yes i don't want to do it in a single delete, but i was stuck on how to break it down to chunks. i tried limit and order by but that is not supported.

Comment: I'm curious -- Did you try nnichols's solution?  How well did it work?

Comment: I tried the solution of DELETE in batch with ROW_NUMBER() subquery and it worked. the create/update operations were working fine while the delete was happening in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using ROW_NUMBER() -

```
SELECT person_id, version_num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY version_num DESC) revs
FROM person_history
```

and for the delete -

```
DELETE ph
FROM person_history ph
JOIN (
    SELECT person_id, version_num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY version_num DESC) revs
    FROM person_history
) t ON ph.person_id = t.person_id
   AND ph.version_num = t.version_num
   AND t.revs > 5;
```

**UPDATE**

I have set up a test table with 1M rows. Running select version of OP's query (which only retains latest 3 versions, not 5 suggested) I get 267,432 rows, but the distribution is likely to be very different.

Query 1: Original correlated sub-query

```
SELECT id
FROM person_history
WHERE id in (
    SELECT p0.id
    FROM person_history p0
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM person_history p1
        WHERE  p0.person_id = p1.person_id
        AND p0.version_num < p1.version_num
    ) >= 3
);
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | person_history |  | index | PRIMARY | uq_person_ver | 4 |  | 998896 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p0 |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 3 | test.person_history.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p1 |  | ref | uq_person_ver | uq_person_ver | 3 | test.p0.person_id | 3 | 33.33 | Using where; Using index |

Query 2: Rewritten correlated sub-query

```
SELECT ph.id
FROM person_history ph
JOIN (
    SELECT p0.id
    FROM person_history p0
    JOIN person_history p1
        ON p0.person_id = p1.person_id
        AND p0.version_num < p1.version_num
    GROUP BY p0.id
    HAVING COUNT(p1.id) >= 3
) t ON ph.id = t.id;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 1148980 | 100.00 |  |
| 1 | PRIMARY | ph |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 3 | t.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | DERIVED | p0 |  | index | PRIMARY,uq_person_ver | PRIMARY | 3 |  | 998896 | 100.00 |  |
| 2 | DERIVED | p1 |  | ref | uq_person_ver | uq_person_ver | 3 | test.p0.person_id | 3 | 33.33 | Using where; Using index |

Query 3: ROW_NUMBER() sub-query

```
SELECT ph.id
FROM person_history ph
JOIN (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY version_num DESC) revs
    FROM person_history
) t ON ph.id = t.id
    AND t.revs > 3;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 998896 | 33.33 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | ph |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 3 | t.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | DERIVED | person_history |  | index |  | uq_person_ver | 4 |  | 998896 | 100.00 | Using index; Using filesort |

**Observations**

| # | Query 1 | Query 2 | Query 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rows examined | 6,378,752 | 534,864 | 1,267,432 |
| Rows returned | 267,432 | 267,432 | 267,432 |
| Execution time | 5.95 | 3.75 | 1.10 |

Combining this with batching on the person_id should significantly reduce the overhead -

```
DELETE ph
FROM person_history ph
JOIN (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY version_num DESC) revs
    FROM person_history
    WHERE person_id BETWEEN 1 AND 50000
) t ON ph.id = t.id
    AND t.revs > 3;
```

I also tried these queries against the table with the surrogate PK replaced by PK on (person_id, version_num) but the improvement was negligible.

Comment: I do not think that ROW_NUMBER() together with >5 is well optimized.  The `SELECT` may be the slow part of this formulation.

Comment: @RickJames - what do you think? I know my test table is much narrower than OP's table but the inner query should be entirely index based, so it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I tried @nnichols's solution of ROW_NUMBER() with a smaller batch of 10k and it solved the problem. The CRUD were working fine, while DELETE was running in the background.